# FromBody EmptyBodyBehavior is ignored when binding on a complex type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

Consider the following

```
[HttpPut("products/{id}/attributes1")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProductAttributesUpdated), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public IActionResult UpdateAttributes1(
    [FromHeader(Name = "X-User")] int userId,
    [FromRoute(Name = "id")] int id,
    [FromBody(EmptyBodyBehavior = EmptyBodyBehavior.Allow)] ProductAttributesUpdate body)
{
    // Omitted for brievity
}

[HttpPut("products/{id}/attributes2")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProductAttributesUpdated), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public IActionResult UpdateAttributes2([FromQuery] ProductAttributesUpdateRequest req)
{
    // Omitted for brievity
}

public class ProductAttributesUpdateRequest
{
    [FromHeader(Name = "X-User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [FromRoute(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [FromBody(EmptyBodyBehavior = EmptyBodyBehavior.Allow)]
    public ProductAttributesUpdate Body { get; set; }
}
```

The first method `UpdateAttributes1` works as expected, *userId* is bound from the header, *id* is bound from the route and *body* is bound from the body and I can omit it in my request.

The second method `UpdateAttributes2` works as long as I provide a body. If I don't, I receive the following response

```
{
    "errors": {
        "Body": [
            "A non-empty request body is required."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-6f616b86f264022bc132c2bf75399235-d8d457f0274b69d2-00"
}
```

I'm assuming the attribute `[FromBody(EmptyBodyBehavior = EmptyBodyBehavior.Allow)]` is ignored by the model binding.

Is there a way to bind on a complex type without having `EmptyBodyBehavior = EmptyBodyBehavior.Allow` be ignored?

Comment: If you don't specific the From attribute for the MVC controller method, it will use Frombody by default. This is the reason why the attribute2 not working.  Besides, I also don't know what's your question is.

Comment: I've edited my question. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to bind on a complex type without having EmptyBodyBehavior = EmptyBodyBehavior.Allow be ignored?

According to your description, if you feel the default model binder doesn't match your requirement, I suggest you could write an custom model binding instead of using default.

Like below:

```
public class MyComplexTypeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Perform custom binding logic here
        // ...

        // Set the resulting object on the binding context
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(myComplexTypeObject);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then you could register the model binder like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new BinderProvider(
            (context) => context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(MyComplexType),
            (context) => new MyComplexTypeModelBinder()
        ));
    });
}
```